# How do I replace NA values in Column B with opposite value of column A

Tags: r, if-statement, na

I have a large dataset. Two of the columns contains YES and No Values. Column.A has 0 NA values while Column.B contains around 40% NA values and dataset holds 500 lines where Col.B is the opposite of Col.A

Sample Columns

```
Col.A          Col.B
Yes             No
Yes             NA
No              Yes
No              yes
Yes             No
No              NA
```

I'm wanting to replace all the NA values in Col.B with what ever the opposite is of Col.A

I have been trying to replace all of Col.B based on Col.A Value using a for loop

```
for (j in 1:500)
{
  if (Col.A == YES )
  {
    Col.B = "NO "
  }
  else
  {
    Col.B = "YES "
  }
}
```

However the IF statement is coming back with 'YES' not found

Comment: To help others answer this question, you may want to provide the code that you used to generate your sample columns. Also, are you sure that you wanted `if (Col.A == YES )` and not `if (Col.A == "YES" )`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use ifelse for this.

#### Strings

```
df$B<-ifelse(is.na(df$B), ifelse(df$A=="YES ", "NO ", "YES "), df$B)


df<-data.frame(A=c("Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes","No"), B=c("No", NA, "Yes", "Yes", "No", NA))
> 
> df
    A    B
1 Yes   No
2 Yes <NA>
3  No  Yes
4  No  Yes
5 Yes   No
6  No <NA>
> 
> df$B<-ifelse(is.na(df$B), ifelse(df$A=="Yes", "No", "Yes"), df$B)
> 
> df
    A   B
1 Yes  No
2 Yes  No
3  No Yes
4  No Yes
5 Yes  No
6  No Yes
```

#### Factors

```
df<-data.frame(A=c("Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes","No"), B=c("No", NA, "Yes", "Yes", "No", NA), stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
> 
> df
    A    B
1 Yes   No
2 Yes <NA>
3  No  Yes
4  No  Yes
5 Yes   No
6  No <NA>
> 
> df$B[is.na(df$B)]<-as.factor(ifelse(df$A[is.na(df$B)]=="Yes","No", "Yes" ))
> 
> df
    A   B
1 Yes  No
2 Yes  No
3  No Yes
4  No Yes
5 Yes  No
6  No Yes
```

Comment: When used Column B becomes a column of Strings containing either "YES" or "1"

 Col.B is showing as "YES " "YES " "1"    "YES " "1"    "1"    "YES " "1"    "1"    "1"    "1"    "1"    "1"

Comment: I've updated the answer to show the results I got when I used your sample data.

Comment: Another update that works when you have factors rather than strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
#Convert the columns to characters
df[] <- lapply(df, as.character)
#Change NA and A = 'Yes' to 'No'
df$B[is.na(df$B) & df$A == 'Yes'] <- 'No'
#change remaining values to 'Yes'
df$B[is.na(df$B)] <- 'Yes'
```